# Pass arguments from script to PHP interpreter is not working with quotes, why?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, php

I need to create a wrapper script for PHP interpreter (already in PATH):

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is a wrapper for the PHP interpreter.
#
# We prepare the enviroment for SQL Anywhere PHP extension sourcing
# /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh and then we call the PHP
# interpreter already in the PATH passing -dextension=sqlanywere.so which
# enable the PHP extension.
#
# Don't enable sqlanywhere.so globally becase for some reason this will
# break the command "plesk bin php_handler". In addition the extension
# requires the SQLANY17 environment variable which is hard to set with
# CGI/FastCGI at this time.
php $@
```

My `php-wrapper` however is not working properly with quotes. For example, this works with the original interpreter:

```
php-r 'echo "Works";'
```

Running `php-wrapper` with the same arguments:

```
./php-wrapper -r 'echo "Works";'
```

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in Command line code on line 1

How can I debug arguments `$@` to see what's happening and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `$@` in double quotes, thusly:

```
php "$@"
```

What's happening is that the arguments to `php-wrapper` are `-r` and `echo "Works";` which is fine. However, because `$@` isn't quoted, all the arguments `php-wrapper` receives are parsed as separate words, so `php` is being passed `-r`, `echo`, and `"Works"`. *With* the double-quoted `$@`, `php` will be passed `-r` and `echo "Works"`.

From the `bash` manual page:

```
   @      Expands to the positional parameters, starting from  one.   When
          the  expansion  occurs  within  double  quotes,  each  parameter
          expands to a separate word.  That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1"
          "$2"  ...
```

Here's a little script I use when argument parsing isn't happening the way I want it to:

```
$ cat echoargs
#!/bin/bash --

count=0

for i in "$@"
do
    echo "$count: $i"

    ((count++));
done
```

Change your wrapper script to:

```
echoargs $@
echo ====
echoargs "$@"
```

and then try various invocations of the wrapper to see what it's passing on.